# Trigger a Postback in when File is Uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Note: I want to trigger a postback without clicking any button. I don't think FileUpload triggers any postback or does it. How would I handle something like this?

`<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AutoPostback="true"  />`

I tried adding a onchange="mymethod" and for some reason I get mymethod is not defined error which doesn't make sense because I clearly defined it. What else should I try